# How to toggle a read-only view in mysql workbench

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I am the superuser of a particular database schema. Therefore I have all privileges on the tables in this schema, including `ALTER` `DELETE` `UPDATE` and `INSERT`.

I am administrating this database using the GUI MySQL Workbench 6.3. I used to select rows and to obtain a read-only result grid, which was convenient because it prevented me from accidentally editing data in my table.

This was indicated by a 'read only' flag in the bottom right corner of the result grid (see below).

[image: 'read only' flag in the bottom right corner of the result grid]

However, I did not change anything in the structure of the table, and now when I select rows I am able to edit data and the 'read only' flag has disappeared.

I find it a bit unsecure because it would mean I could accidentally edit data in the table by mistyping.

How could I revert to a read-only result display?

Comment: Note: MySQL workbench cannot work without a primary key if that's your issue. However if you have a many to many table you can set both columns as primary keys which will let you edit the data.

Answer (score 5):

The rules that allow editing a result set are very strict. The select query must be a plain one - no aggregate functions, no joins, no unions. There must be a primary key which is used to address the records to be changed.

Comment: I am aware of this, but what I am aiming to do here is the reverse: I would like to display in a read-only mode a request that is eligible NOT to be read-only, i.e. a request without aggregate functions and on a table that has a PK.

Comment: update: all things considered, it doesn't matter so much. Because any accidental edit would need to be committed, and this is asked explicitely by the software. Anyway, thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3):

Update: it wasn't necessary to worry about accidentally editing records in the table while not being in read-only mode.

Indeed, if you change a record in the table (in the screenshot below, I changed a year from 2010 to 2020), for this change to be actually committed in the database, you would need to click the "apply" button in the bottom right corner.

Moreover, upon closing the tab, you are asked whether or not you want to save changes. Consequently, if you accidentally edited a record, you just have to click "Don't save" upon closing the tab.

[image]